# ng-repeat orderBy position is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm writing an Angular App that has a menu, I divided it this way:

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav" ng-repeat="menuItem in menu |  orderBy:'position'">
    <!-- Home  Mega Menu -->
    <li class="mega-menu">
        <a href="index-corporate.html">{{menuItem.testo}}</a>
    </li>
    <!-- Shortcode Menu Ends -->
    <!-- Header Search -->
    <li class="hidden-767" ng-show="$last">
        <a href="#" class="header-search">
            <span>
                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
            </span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
...
$scope.menu = [
    {testo: 'Home', link: 'index.html', position: 1},
    {testo: 'Due', link: 'index.html', position: 2},
    {testo: 'Tre', link: 'index.html', position: 3},
];
...
```

The result is rendering this way: `Tre`, `Due`, `Home` instead of rendering by position `Home`, `Due`, `Tre`.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Use `-menuItem.position` in the orderBy argument

Comment: Its working here http://plnkr.co/edit/LEDDI0TX6OvKj0gNJrSl?p=preview what is the problem?

Comment: It works for  me. Refresh or open a private tab on browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `reverse` as described in the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy):

```
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav" ng-repeat="menuItem in menu |  orderBy:'position':reverse">
```

Comment: in his case OP don't need to mention `reverse` parameter, see here http://plnkr.co/edit/LEDDI0TX6OvKj0gNJrSl?p=preview

Comment: This works, but why should I reverse the order? I put 1, 2, 3, why is it showing the other way around?

Comment: Oh right. It work for me as well (without the `:reverse`)